# missing ) after argument list error

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing the following code in a variable of JS to execute a function

```
"<p class='custom-popup-button-text' onclick='return goToNewsUrl("+news_url+");'>Detail News</p>"
```

Its returning following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If `goToNewsUrl()` takes a string then you are missing quotes. You should show us what the resulting js looks like after evaluating that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`news_url` must be wrapped by quotes:

```
'<p class="custom-popup-button-text" onclick="return goToNewsUrl(\'' + news_url + '\');">Detail News</p>'
```